# CSS - Internet Explorer won't show box-shadow & transition

Tags: css, internet-explorer, transform, transition, box-shadow

**I'm attempting to highlight a div using transition & box-shadow.**

```
  transition: transform .8s ease-in;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
```

**I get it to function in Chrome but not IE. What do you suggest?**

***---
Update May 1st, 2020
---***

I narrowed down my problem. If I change the display to block or table it works but by default the element is a table-row. When I change the display it works but throws off my styling. Any particular clue what the difference between "table" and "table-row" displays?

Answer (score 0):

try to use this following code :

```
transition: transform .8s ease-in;
box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
-webkit-transition: transform .8s ease-in;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the **transform** from the line below then it will work in IE 11 browser.

```
 transition: transform .8s ease-in;
```

Test code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition:.8s ease-in;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

div:hover {
  width: 300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

 <div>Test</div><br>

 <p><b>Note:</b> This example does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Output in IE 11 browser.

[image]

If the issue persists then please try to inform us which version of the IE browser you are using for making this test? What is the purpose of using **transform** with **transition**? What exact output do you want to get in the IE browser? If possible then try to provide the sample code with HTML and CSS that we can try to run and test with the IE and other browsers to see the difference in the results.

Comment: I'm using a Mac so I'm using Safari to simulate IE 11. I'm mainly just trying to get the box shadow to work.

Comment: I suggest you try to test the issue on the actual IE browser instead of simulating the IE in the Safari browser. It can help to know the accurate results for the IE browser. Let us know about your testing results in the actual IE browser.